# RecyclerView.clear()? Is there a method to clear() or invalidate a viewholder data individually?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I came across [the documentation for AsyncPagedListDiffer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/paging/AsyncPagedListDiffer). I'm wondering how we can call `holder.clear()` when `holder` is a `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` instance. Maybe they have an in-house method which accommodates this clearance functionality?

Comment: I also searched more about this, but found no luck!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the code sample on that page, `UserViewHolder` is assumed to be an extension (that you write) of `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` that implements additional `bindTo` and `clear` methods.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Even I have anticipated the same. Any clue what they have written inside the clear() method of ViewHolder. Is anything similar to invalidate()?